# AS3: Removing child that is created within a for loop from outside of the loop

Tags: actionscript-3, function, loops, textfield

I have a for loop which creates text fields from an array to represent high scores. Each level in my game has a seperate loop to do this (which work absolutely fine), here is an example:

```
// LEVEL 1 HIGH SCORES //
if (currentLevel==1) {
for (var k:int = 0; k < lvl1highScores.length; k++) //loop the length of the lvl 1 score array
{
var tf:HighScoreTF = new HighScoreTF();
tf.txt.text = lvl1highScores[k].player + " - " + lvl1highScores[k].score;
tf.y = k * 35; //sets distance between each high score text field
addChild(tf);
}
}
```

What I would like to do is remove all of these text fields (tf) from view once the user has clicked away from the high score chart. This would be done from a seperate function to the one which creates the text fields.

Using removeChild doesn't work because the child won't have been created when the game is initially started.

All help is most appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first of all, having a separate `for` loop for every single level is terrible practice, so you might want to rethink how you're doing this. However, if you really just want a simple solution to the existing problem, you should just create a container for all your objects, then remove the container.

```
var highScoreFields:Sprite = new Sprite();
if (currentLevel == 1) {
    // ...
    highScoreFields.addChild(tf);
    // ...
}
addChild(highScoreFields);
```

You can then remove the container, which will detach all of its children from the display chain, simply by calling `removeChild(highScoreFields)`.

Comment: Hi Jake, thanks for your response. I tried your method and am now getting the following error message when trying to view high scores: 'ArgumentError: Error #2012: DisplayObjectContainer$ class cannot be instantiated.'. Any idea how I can solve this? I followed your instructions exactly so shouldn't really be any isssues. Cheers!

Comment: @TomHaddad Whoops, sorry about that. I forgot that `DisplayObjectContainer` is abstract. Try using `Sprite` instead. I've updated my code accordingly.